# Small stepper, simple driver

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, buffer

It's a very small [stepper](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/20pcs-lot-10MM-Micro-stepper-motor-2-phase-4-wire-stepper-motor-digital-camera-cash-register/1610488420.html) at 18 ohm resistance per coil(2 of them) (4 phase).

[image]

I got: stepper in the picture, L9110, LM358, arduino.

I used an L9110 with the arduino. The stepper moved where it was supposed to move but with a lot of noise, vibrations during some frequencies. At higher frequencies it moved very smooth but at lower frequencies it became a clock. "tick", "tock", "tick", "tock".

**I want to step with a sine wave signal. I want it to have an amplitude of 3V. How do I make such a circuit?** 

3 V / 18 ohm = 0.16 A

3 V * 0.16 A = ½ watt

My previous ideas that have failed:

- Use two pins (filtered pwm) on the arduino. 
  Fail: they can only give
  20 mA safely. (18 ohm * 20 mA * 20 mA = 0.0072 watt). Too weak.
- ^Use above idea with two LM358 as buffer for the two pins. 
  Fail: LM358 outputs about 1 mA (0V gnd, 5V vcc).
- Use a linear analog voltage regulator. 
  Fail: It will be ineffecient and I don't have a linear analog voltage regulator. Though I could buy one.
- Use L9110. 
   Fail: It only has a truth table. There's no analog voltages.

Since it's just a very small stepper that won't use more than ½ Watt I should be able to get away with a few components.

When it comes to software and digital things I'm a king. When it comes to analog circuits I'm a peasant. Please help this peasant you analog kings and queens.

Comment: Combine the first bullet with the last one. Feed it PWM through a driver (no filtering should be needed if the frequency is high enough).

Comment: H-Bridge + PWM = Stepper motor driver.

Comment: @TomCarpenter So no filtering? Won't this produce sound? If I use filtering will it cover the ½ watt?

Comment: @EugeneSh. "Bullet", is that the LM358?

Comment: Depends on the PWM frequency. There comes a point when the inductance of the motor winding will act as a filter and smooth out the PWM signal. There is a limit to how high you can go which comes down how fast the transistors in the driver can switch - if you switch them too fast you can end up with both high side and low side on at the same time resulting in a lot of heat dissipation in the driver.

Comment: You can use a pair of the L9110 drivers (one for each coil/phase) and then use PWM to sequence the coils and control the voltage (ustepping), but you would have to check what frequency the driver chip can operate at.

Comment: @HarrySvensson "Bullet" = point in the list

Comment: You know... they sell stepper motor drivers with 128 micro-steps for $2-$3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly what I need is called a [Push-Pull Amplifier](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transistors).

This is the [schematic](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+3.5993318835628396+43+5+50%0At+352+224+384+224+0+1+-4.077338222298865+0.46508329399295567+100%0At+384+240+416+240+0+1+-4.542421516291821+0.580461306916052+100%0Aw+384+208+416+208+0%0Aw+416+224+416+208+0%0Aw+416+256+416+288+0%0Aw+416+288+432+288+0%0Aw+464+288+480+288+0%0Aw+480+288+480+256+0%0At+512+240+480+240+0+1+-1.7355515018159826+0.7011700018614375+100%0At+544+224+512+224+0+1+-1.1497595128755922+0.5857919889403904+100%0Aw+480+224+480+208+0%0Aw+480+208+512+208+0%0At+512+336+480+336+0+-1+3.966551368203418+-0.596727128119162+100%0At+544+352+512+352+0+-1+3.4852022530063627+-0.48134911519705526+100%0At+384+336+416+336+0+-1+1.1761311952625562+-0.7009859815295709+100%0At+352+352+384+352+0+-1+0.5905232266540336+-0.5856079686085226+100%0Aw+416+352+416+368+0%0Aw+416+368+384+368+0%0Aw+480+352+480+368+0%0Aw+480+368+512+368+0%0Aw+480+320+480+288+0%0Aw+416+288+416+320+0%0Ad+544+320+544+352+1+0.805904783%0Ad+544+256+544+288+1+0.805904783%0Ad+352+256+352+288+1+0.805904783%0Ad+352+320+352+352+1+0.805904783%0Ar+352+352+352+432+0+10000%0Ar+544+352+544+432+0+10000%0Ar+352+224+352+144+0+10000%0Ar+544+224+544+144+0+10000%0Aw+480+208+480+144+1%0Aw+480+144+544+144+1%0Aw+416+144+352+144+1%0Aw+416+368+416+432+1%0Aw+480+368+480+432+1%0Aw+480+432+448+432+0%0Aw+448+432+416+432+0%0Aw+416+432+352+432+0%0Aw+480+432+544+432+0%0Aw+480+144+448+144+0%0Aw+448+144+416+144+0%0AR+448+144+448+64+0+0+40+7+0+0+0.5%0Ag+448+432+448+496+0%0AR+736+288+832+288+0+1+40+1.7+3.2+3.141592653589793+0.5%0AR+160+288+64+288+0+1+40+1.7+3.2+0+0.5%0Aw+544+352+640+352+2%0Aw+352+352+256+352+2%0Aw+256+288+352+288+2%0Aw+352+224+256+224+2%0Aw+544+224+640+224+2%0Aw+544+288+640+288+2%0Aw+416+208+416+144+1%0Aw+480+288+528+288+2%0Aw+416+288+368+288+2%0Ar+432+288+464+288+0+18%0Ad+352+224+352+256+1+0.805904783%0Ad+352+288+352+320+1+0.805904783%0Ad+544+224+544+256+1+0.805904783%0Ad+544+288+544+320+1+0.805904783%0Aw+640+288+736+288+1%0Aw+160+288+256+288+1%0Ao+44+32+0+551+5+0.0015625+0+-1%0Ao+54+32+0+35+5+0.2+1+-1%0Ao+54+32+1+35+1.25+0.00009765625+2+-1%0Ao+43+32+0+35+5+0.003125+3+-1%0A) that I made and decided to go for. In case anyone cares.